# Can't resize "boxed" text without messing up the whole document

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm not a code expert, but I have some experience...
I've been struggling for hours with this problem.

I have this code, and I wanted to have the scrollbar either inside the screen or outside the camera.
I've tried pretty many things, but without success. 
Can you tell me what's wrong?

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="219" background="http://i.imgur.com/G3hEVXm.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="106" height="218" background="http://i.imgur.com/Svp1s1L.png" style="padding-left:110px;padding-right:110px;">
        <div style="width:445px;display:block;overflow:auto;height:218px;max-width:670px;">
          <p style="text-align:left;height:320px;width:300px;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="78" background="http://i.imgur.com/URFZF8I.png"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You aren't closing the `<p>` or `<b>` which probably isn't helping the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue here is that you're trying to use tables - while there can be tweaking done to eventually get this to work, the only real certainty is that you'll end up with a headache.

Consider making one parent div with `position: relative;`, a set height and width, and a `background-image` of the camera image. Then, make a smaller div inside of it, put `position: absolute;` on it, and use `top` and `left` to position it properly where you want it to be.

```css
#parent {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ef/66/27/ef662748d23852026c96e0d06224e6ca.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#parent #child {
    width: 255px;
    height: 173px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 206px;
    left: 245px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

    <div id="child">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed maximus euismod ligula ut suscipit. Morbi viverra congue nulla nec consequat. Nulla nec enim sit amet risus posuere luctus eget ut risus. Phasellus nibh purus, bibendum vitae aliquam nec, finibus vel magna. Praesent iaculis quam non orci suscipit porttitor. Duis id leo vel nulla mattis varius. Nullam bibendum mi et quam commodo tempor.

Praesent urna erat, vehicula et porta id, ultricies maximus odio. Duis augue tortor, faucibus nec neque at, efficitur efficitur lorem. Phasellus pulvinar interdum placerat. Nunc volutpat justo vulputate elit ultricies, nec dignissim lectus dapibus. Aenean sagittis sollicitudin gravida. Quisque rutrum lorem eget gravida posuere. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum imperdiet justo vel erat varius, imperdiet fermentum lectus consectetur. Praesent sollicitudin ac turpis id imperdiet. Integer in ante efficitur, convallis sem in, gravida ex. Fusce a consectetur sapien. Mauris dignissim augue vitae molestie convallis.
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:** You mentioned below in the comments that you can't directly manipulate the CSS. In that case, you can put the styles on the elements in-line just as you have in your example. I've created an example using in-line styles [here](https://jsfiddle.net/agsva5kx/).

Comment: Thing is, css won't work where I'm editing this. I guess only html works

Comment: What exactly are you doing that "CSS won't work"? Is this an HTML page? If so, you'll need to wrap it in `<style>` tags and put it in the `<head>` of your page. Otherwise, you can put the CSS on the elements in-line as you have in your example and it will work the same. I'll make a quick example. **EDIT:** [Here ya go](https://jsfiddle.net/agsva5kx/)

Comment: I'm trying to create a Geocache Listing, on the geocaching website. It was boxes of text where either you in put normal text or basic html.
I've pasted that code you've just gave me and this was the result: https://i.snag.gy/iKZkDx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Confirming what [Santi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2026606/santi) says and here is what you can have with table way. If the place you tried to put this code does not have support external css, you can try converting all styles inline.

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.cam-upper {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/G3hEVXm.png") no-repeat;
  height: 219px;
}
.cam-body {
  padding-left: 110px;
  width: 600px;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Svp1s1L.png") no-repeat;
}
.cam-lower {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/URFZF8I.png") no-repeat;
  height: 78px;
}
.cam-screen {
  width: 320px;
  display: block;
  height: 218px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cam-upper"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nopadding">
      <td class="cam-body">
        <div class="cam-screen">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonummy repellat habitasse pede proin, nunc odio aut magna nunc, nisl tellus fusce rutrum, nunc nibh nullam nunc ut.</p>
          <p>Vitae rutrum maecenas suscipit, in quam ac porttitor pharetra, sit litora rhoncus elementum amet.</p>
          <p>Ipsum nulla vitae penatibus lorem, nunc mus nisl sit, sem felis nullam gravida dui, ipsum at vitae consectetuer bibendum.</p>
          <p>Habitant cras orci et, amet pede aenean dis, mauris accumsan donec vitae, vitae felis faucibus nam eget.</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cam-lower"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```